# Auto ARIMA Model in R

Tags: r, arima

I am using the forecast package in R to implement ARIMA Models. I am using one variable, the data is from 2016 to 2019 and it is monthly. When I look at the residual check, the 2016 residuals do not look correct. There is a flat like for 2016 and this is having an impact on tuning the model. I am looking for advice on how to fix this issue.

[image: Data]

[image: auto.arima output]

[image: Residual Plot]

````
fit.arima <- auto.arima(RevenueDataTSTest)

checkresiduals(fit.arima)

```
````

Comment: How are you tuning the model and what exactly is the "impact" on it?

Comment: I have not done any tuning at this point. 2016 residuals should not be 0. If I removed 2016, and used 2017 to 2019, 2017 residuals are 0. I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: The first 12 months are used to initialize the seasonal terms.